# How to optimize SELECT COUNT(*) from multiple tables?

Tags: sql

Can this be optimized?

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE key = 'value')
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE another_key = 'another_value')
```

EDIT:
key and another_key are both primary keys.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Indexed on key and another_key

Comment: @nicomp key and another_key are primary keys.

Comment: Are they clustered keys?

Comment: @nicomp No. Surrogate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `key` and `another_key` are both primary keys.

You can try another way `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT t1.cnt,t2.cnt FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table_1 WHERE key = 'value') t1 CROSS JOIN     
(SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table_2 WHERE another_key = 'another_value') t2
```

Answer (score 2):

The only performance improvement would be indexes:

- `table_1(key)`
- `table_2(another_key)`

You are returning one row from each table, so the style of joining doesn't matter.